# is switching glPixelStorei a slow operation?

Tags: opengl

I have lots of different formats RBG, RBGA and ALPHA and loading textures requires changing GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT between 1 and 4. Is this worth caching? Say having a variable "alignment" and calling glPixelStorei only if state differs vs calling glPixelStorei all the time.

Same idea as with texture switching.

Comment: Generally you want to minimize state change, but are you really loading a lot of textures in your main display loop?  I wouldn't worry about the performance of `glPixelStorei` if you're only calling it during scene setup/loading.

Comment: Currently I'm rendering text which gets uploaded when needed. Only first access to character is affected - not every frame. I might consider dynamic loading/unloading textures going forward.

Comment: If it isn't happening with any kind of frequency, I'd say it's premature to be concerned about it.  There are probably ~100 other things taking up far more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's consider this.

Every time you change `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`, you are also about to call `glTexSubImage`. This function will, *at best*, provoke a DMA operation from client memory into OpenGL's internal texture memory. If you're not using PBOs, then this also means that the function will have to copy that client memory into internal storage to do the DMA. And even if you are using PBOs, *you're* going to have to do that copy operation into that memory.

Do you honestly think that changing the state of pack alignment will mean *anything* performance-wise next to the operations you're doing right after? Do you think that computing the bitmap of a glyph or uploading the bitmap data to a texture will be *faster* than changing that piece of state?

Don't worry about it.